# Tkinter check button not working when in another window

Tags: python, tkinter

When you run this code and try and check the the check button and click the button to print out the value of the check button it does not work. I can't figure out why. It prints out 0 whether checked or unchecked.

```
from tkinter import *

def awesome():
    def click_me():
        print(var.get())
        return

    root = Tk()
    root.title("a good try")
    var = IntVar()
    x = Checkbutton(root, text = "check me", variable = var)
    y = Button(root, text = "click me", command = click_me)
    x.pack()
    y.pack()
    root.mainloop()
    return

def main():
    main = Tk()
    cool = Button(main, text = "click", command = awesome)
    cool.pack()
    main.mainloop()
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

change `root = Tk()` to `root = Toplevel()`

need to use `Toplevel()` for a window that opens on another window.